# Can't use custom images as icons using the "icon" property for android and IOS nativescript

Tags: android, ios, typescript, nativescript

I'm trying to use the "icon" property in the Navigation button tag to use a custom image as an icon.

It works on Android, but in iOS the image is oversized. I can't resize it using scss or setting the height in the tags itself.

I can't even set the visibility property to false using platform specific css on iOS to view the default

How can I:

- Make the image hidden on iOS, and make the default

  Resize the Image. [image of HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJbun.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We would love to help but there is not enough information in your question. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to ask a question about an error and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Can you please help me with icon issue in nativescript-angular as well  @DavidRawson I am using ```<NavigationButton icon="res://ic_menu" (tap)=(openDrawer) </NavigationButton>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code base where we can see what you have tried is always good practice in StackOverflow.

However, if we assume that you are using **res://** like this

```
<NavigationButton icon="res://ic_menu" />
```

the solution is to provide different scaled images in your resources folder located in app/App_Resources/iOS (or Android). See how to handle different images for different screen sizes from your App_Resources [here for iOS](http://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/creating-launch-screens-ios) and here for [Android](http://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/creating-launch-screens-android).

However if you want to use one image and control it with CSS and the image properties (width, height, ect) you might create your own folder, for example ***images*** and use it with relative

```
<Image src="~/images/logo.png" stretch ="none" / >
```

Comment: Thank you Nick, using res:// worked perfectly, and that is the only way to correctly use customized icons, no point of trying any other ways.